# how to find count of certain string from multiple text file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a multiple text files and I need to find and count unique specific words in those files.

Like we need to find how many users logged in for certain time from multiple log files.

I have created the following code, its working fine for lesser files but for multiple larger files its taking too much time

```
   $A =Get-Content C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Documents\Python\Test\*.log | ForEach-Object { $wrds=$_.Split(" "); foreach ($i in $wrds) {  Write-Output $i } } | Sort-Object | Get-Unique | select-string  -pattern "AAA" -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch
```

is it possible to finetune this to run faster.

Comment: Please edit your question with approximate sizes for the "larger files", a sample of the text that you are working with and what the intended output should look like i.e. just a count or information about users - should it be unique, etc.

Comment: Hi, if i use this script for 50 text files its working fine but if i run it for 1000 txt file its taking too much time. I just only need the count. If i cant get user name that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to find certain user logins occurring in many log files, based on your use of `Select-String`.

```
# an array of usernames to search for
$users = 'user1', 'user2', 'userX'
# create a regex from this array by joining the values with regex 'OR' (the pipe symbol)
[regex]$regex = ($users | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

# or if you need whole string matches instead of allowing partial matches, use
# [regex]$regex = '\b({0})\b' -f (($users | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|')

# get a list of all log files
$logFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\XXXXXXX\Documents\Python\Test' -Filter '*.log' -File

# loop trhough the list of log files and find the matches in each of them
$result = foreach ($file in $logFiles) {
    $allmatches = $regex.Matches(($file | Get-Content -Raw))
    $logins = @($allmatches.Value | Select-Object -Unique)
    if ($logins.Count) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            LogFile    = $file.FullName
            LoginCount = $logins.Count
            Users      = $logins -join ', '
        }
    }
}

# visual output
$result | Out-GridView -Title 'Login search results'

# or save as CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\somewhere\results.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```